# Correctly translating "Assume" and "Suppose" to German in Mathematics

Tags: translation, english-to-german, mathematics

It is common in mathematics in English to use the words *assume* and *suppose* differently, that is, to use the word *assume* when dealing with a reduction or case, while using the word *suppose* when looking for a contradiction. For example, one may use the phrases "Thus, it can be assumed that..." and "For the sake of contradiction, suppose that... ."

I have seen the word *angenommen* used in mathematics in German, but I am not sure whether it encompasses what both *assume* and *suppose* mean in English or not. Does it? Or is there another word that is also used?

I am aware of the words *annehmen* and *ausgegangen*, but I have not seen them in mathematical texts before.

Comment: As a German who has published mathematics in English, I was not consciously aware of that distinction. That may be just me, but also maybe the distinction is less strict in German.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Let's assume p is a prime.*

> Setzen wir voraus, p sei prim.

*Let's suppose p is a prime.*

> Nehmen wir an, p sei prim.

---

*Voraussetzen* is much stronger than *annehmen*.

> Nehmen Sie etwa an, wir hätten viel Geld? — Das setze ich voraus, sonst wären Sie doch gar nicht hier.

Comment: Is there a way to use these without a pronoun while remaining formal?

Comment: @Schroder Yes, by using the participle: _Angenommen, p ist prim_ and _Vorausgesetzt, p sei prim_

Comment: In addition: There's also "davon ausgehen", as mentioned in the question ("Gehen wir davon aus, dass p prim ist"), which also means *to assume*.

Comment: Without a pronoun that would be "Davon ausgehend"

Answer (score 2):

One common phrase in mathematics (I think, it is the standard phrase) is

> Sei X ...

which is the translation of

> Let X be ...

Comment: You are right, there is also a third common phrase. How does `assume` and `suppose` fit in with their translation?

Answer (score 2):

The use in German is identical to the use in English.

- **angenommen** is a typical beginning of a proof by contradiction. Look at the section *Indirekter Beweis* in the wikipedia-article [Beweis (Mathematik)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beweis_(Mathematik)).
- **vorausgesetzt** means that you make an assumption for a theorem. Other ways to express it are "Unter der Voraussetzung, dass ..." or simply "Sei ... erfüllt." See
  jonathan.scholbach's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Oft benutzt: “Ohne Beschränkung der Allgemeinheit”. Zum Beispiel x >= y und y <= x sind möglich. Der Beweis für den zweiten Fall ist genau umgekehrt vom ersten Fall. Also beweise ich den Fall x>= y und den anderen Fall kannst du selber machen wenn Du Langeweile hast. “Ohne Beschränkung der Allgemeinheit sei x>=
Y”.

Comment: Wlog is not what the question asked for.